# Plotting monthly data with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to use ggplot to plot monthly data that looks like this

```
  count     date
      6 Oct 2010
     23 Nov 2010
     20 Dec 2010
     16 Jan 2011
     64 Oct 2011
     ...
    425 Jul 2012
    436 Aug 2012
    405 Sep 2012
```

where date is of yearmon class from the zoo package.

This was my call:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=count))+geom_line()
```

and this error came up: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.

So ggplot doesn't support the yearmon class, which is fine.

Then I tried to convert yearmon to Date. Now the data looks like this:

```
 count       date
     6 2010-10-01
    23 2010-11-01
    20 2010-12-01
    16 2011-01-01
    64 2011-10-01
   ...
   425 2012-07-01
   436 2012-08-01
   405 2012-09-01
```

and I made the same call, and this was  [the resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcLTw.png)  (sorry about the href... new users aren't allowed to post images)

There is a drop at the end of the plot that shouldn't be there, because data$count had the similar values on the last few rows.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Thanks for reading,

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to recreate the problem with the line dropping unexpectedly on the right of the plot. Here is the code I used, and the output:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = read.table(header=TRUE, colClasses=c("numeric", "Date"),
text=" count       date
     6 2010-10-01
    23 2010-11-01
    20 2010-12-01
    16 2011-01-01
    64 2011-10-01
   425 2012-07-01
   436 2012-08-01
   405 2012-09-01")

plot_1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=date, y=count)) + geom_line()
ggsave("plot_1.png", plot_1, height=4.5, width=4.5)
```

[image]

You might consider posting your data before and after the date conversion (using `dput()`) to help people reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for checking up on this. It did turn out to be a problem with the data on the SQL database. I didn't notice that some records were deleted some the October updates were bumped into the middle. Newbie mistake. Thanks for your time.